# why do special charatcers(#) in eclipse path affect its installation?

Tags: eclipse

I was trying to install eclipse but was getting -"java started but returned with exit code 13" error .This is the error that usually comes when we have problem in  java path variable and so I made all the required changes in eclipse.ini file as well as system variables, but still the error continued....

Later I found (thanks to stack overflow) that problem was with the name of a folder inside which I had my eclipse placed. As soon as I removed # from the name, eclipse started working.

**My concern is how can a folder name affect eclipse installation when all the path mentioned and everything else is perfect??**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#` signs can have special meaning on the unix/linux/bash command line

For instance on a bash command line, you can use the pound sign to write a comment like this:

```
echo "blah blah" # Here I am saying blah blah only for illustrative purpose.
```

In other words, the command line would ignore everything after the `#` sign

On the windows command line, a pound sign [shouldn't be](http://simplyadvanced.net/blog/cheat-sheet-for-windows-command-prompt/) a problem, but since Eclipse is meant to be cross platform. The judgement was probably made to dissuade developers that work on Windows from using pound signs in their paths, because that would break their project as soon as someone tried loading their project with Eclipse on a Linux machine.